# SQL order by absolute values

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have some data in my table below

```
table_1
     column_1     column_2
        1           10
        1           20
        1           30
        1           40
        1           50
        2           -10
        2           -20
        2           -30
        2           -40
        2           -50
```

I want to change this result to something like this

```
 column_1     column_2
    1           10
    2           -10
    1           20
    2           -20
    1           30
    2           -30
    1           40
    2           -40
    1           50
    2           -50
```

I am not sure if there is a way to do this using order by? What I am trying to show is I am trying to show (10,-10) as a group of data

Comment: Is it a requirement that, in case of ties of the absolute value, positive comes before negative?

Comment: @JeroenMostert, yeah you can look at it this way, I want to do it as (10, -10) as a group of data

Comment: The result set is just a bunch of rows, not a group of any kind. The order in which you return them isn't "grouping". If you want that, you could just do it on the client side, or you want a more complicated query that does group things somehow ([with `GROUP BY` and some concatenation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/273238/how-to-use-group-by-to-concatenate-strings-in-sql-server)).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can simply use [`ABS()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189800.aspx) function, that returns the absolute value of a number :

```
SELECT * FROM YourTable
ORDER BY ABS(Column_2),column_2 desc
```

This query will be ordered by the absolute value of `Column_2`

Answer (score 11):

```
SELECT * 
FROM <table>
ORDER BY abs(column_2), column_2 desc
```

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you want to sort on the absolute value of the second column, then the first column.

```
select column_1, column_2 from table_1 order by abs(column_2),column_1
```